# Why im getting exception index was out of range inside the scroll bar event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have t his code in the scroll bar event:

```
if (_fi.Length > 0)
{
    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
    myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = _fi.Length - 1;
    tt = list_of_histograms[myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value];
    HistogramGraphs1.DrawHistogram(tt);
    long res = GetTopLumAmount(tt, 1000);
    long max = GetHistogramMaximum(tt);
    GetHistogramAverage(tt);
    setpicture(myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value);
    this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

With the following variables defined:

```
_fi = FileInfo[]
tt = long[]
list_of_histograms = List<long[]>
```

When i move the bar to the end to the right it's getting to frame 1047 and then throw the exception.
When the exception is thrown i see that :

`_fi.Length = 1049` (-1 so its 1048) so if its starting from 0 its like 0 to 1047)

```
list_of_histograms.Count = 1048
myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value = 1048
```

I know what the exception means the question is why it happend if i,m doing `_fi.Length - 1` as length ?

Comment: Why is `_fi.Length` relevant when you're not accessing `_fi` but `list_of_histograms`?

Comment: Which line does the exception originate from? What is `list_of_histograms`?

Comment: setting `myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = _fi.Length - 2;` will fix your problem.

Comment: @KingKing not really, when `_fi` will have 1050 items it will break again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array `_fi` might contain more items than `list_of_histograms`. To avoid error just set max value according to proper list:

```
myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Maximum = list_of_histograms.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the **1048** element (`myTrackPanelss1.trackBar1.Value = 1048`) of a list which has elements from 0 to **1047** (`list_of_histograms.Count = 1048`).

Apparently you have less histograms than files. What's wrong here, as well as a real fix, depends on your application logic.